# Javascript function to compare two arrays in sequence

Tags: javascript

I have two JavaScript arrays, an example is:

```
array1 = ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];
array2 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
```

As you can see the second array has had new elements added.

I would like to create a function, that would track what is added or deleted relative to array2.

For example the above arrays would return:

```
function getStatus(array1, array2) {
  return ['A added', 'B matched', 'C matched', 'D matched', 'E matched', 'F added'];
}
```

As you can see, the sequence is important.

I appreciate anyones help.

example1:

```
array1 = ['England', 'Scotland', 'Wales'];
array2 = ['Scotland', 'Wales'];
```

> ['England deleted', 'Scotland matched', 'Wales matched']

example2:

```
array1 = ['Scotland', 'Wales'];
array2 = ['England', 'Scotland', 'Wales'];
```

> ['England added', 'Scotland matched', 'Wales matched']

example3:

```
array1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];
array2 = ['B', 'C', 'E'];
```

> ['A deleted', 'B matched', 'C matched', 'D deleted', 'E matched']

example4: (there can also be duplicate items - see example7 too)

```
array1 = ['A', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'B', 'A'];
array2 = ['B', 'C', 'E', 'A'];
```

> ['A deleted', 'B matched', 'C added', 'D deleted', 'E matched', 'B deleted', 'A matched']

example5:

```
array1 = ['B', 'C', 'E', 'A'];
array2 = ['A', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'B', 'A'];
```

> ['A added', 'B matched', 'C deleted', 'D added', 'E matched', 'B added', 'A matched']

example6:

```
array1 = ['England', 'Scotland', 'Wales'];
array2 = ['Scotland', 'Wales', 'England'];
```

> ['England deleted', 'Scotland matched', 'Wales matched', 'England added']

example7:

```
array1 = ['A', 'B']
array2 = ['C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'];
```

> ['C added', 'A matched', 'B matched', 'A added', 'B added']

example8 (C is added and deleted because it does not fit the sequence that has already started from A):

```
array1 = ['A', 'C']
array2 = ['C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'];
```

> ['C added', 'A matched', 'B added', 'A added', 'B added', 'C deleted']

Comment: are the values unique? what have you tried?

Comment: @NinaScholz, thanks for your reply. No the values are not unique. If you look at an example I gave `[A, B, D, E, B, A]`, you can see there can be duplicates.

Comment: @adiga, each time I try something, I throw it away. If I manage to do something that I think is useful, I will attach it to my question.

Comment: In `array1 = [A, B, D, E, B, A];
array2 = [B, C, E, A];`, Why is `'A deleted'` at the beginning and `'A matched'` at the end. Does the order matter? How to identify the order when elements could be missing or added in either of the arrays?

Comment: @adiga, yes the order does matter.  That's what makes this question complex.  I think you need to try establish a sequence with what is comparable between the two arrays.

Comment: @Richard what output do you expect when array1 = ['A', 'B'] and array2 = ['C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'];?

Comment: likely what you want is to build the longest common substring, (and trivially add the deleted added nodes in between)

Comment: @GauravDhiman, good question. I have added your example to my question above.

Comment: @Richard why not `['C added', 'A added', 'B added', 'A matched', 'B matched']`?, i asked the question because there can be many cases like this and there is no `precise` problem statement just some examples.

Comment: @GauravDhiman it matches the first sequence it finds. A sequence and consist of one or more items. I'll give another example (`example8`) above.

Comment: note that your example 8 is contradictory with England from example 6. I am assuming (once again) you want to maximize the number of elems matched (with constraint they are found in order)

Comment: @grodzi, Can you explain?  I don't see a contradiction. If items are out of sequence, they are marked as `added/deleted`. If they are matching a sequence, they are marked as `matched`.

Comment: You are stating for example 8 that: A starts a sequence. (because it matches A from array2 at idx 1 (assuming array are 0-indexed)). In example 6, England starts a sequence (because it matches England from array2 at idx 2). However you don't consider England matching (which leads only one element in common) but delete it for the sequence Scotland-Wales

Comment: @grodzi, I see what your'e saying, in `example6` should the sequence start with `England` or `Scotland`? The reason it should start with `Scotland` (i.e. `Scotland-Wales`), is because that is the larger sequence (`Scotland-Wales` sequence is 2 and the `England` sequence is 1).  I do see your point though, for example what happens if you have two equal sequences, which one do you use? I think in this case, use either, and mark the other as `added/deleted`.

Comment: what do you prefer of `[A, B]` and `[B, A]` or `[A, B, C, D, E, F]` and `[D, E, F, A, B, C]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this

```
function findChange(before, after) {
    const result = [];
  for(let a of after) {
    const idx = before.indexOf(a);
    if (idx == -1) {
        result.push(`${a} is Added`);
    }
    else {
      before.slice(0, idx).forEach(a => result.push(`${a} is Deleted`));
      before = before.slice(idx + 1);
      result.push(`${a} is Matched`);
    }
    }
    before.forEach(a => result.push(`${a} is Deleted`));
  return result;
}
```

It doesnt give correct answer for `8th` example, but from comments you seem to be okay to print either of the sequence

---

Here is LCS Based (Bottom Up) Implementation, as @grodzi pointed out for case 4-5 first implementation is not really good.

```
function LCATable(before, after) {
    const table = Array(after.length + 1).fill(0).map(() => Array(before.length + 1).fill(0));
  for (let i = after.length - 1; i >= 0 ; --i) {
    for(let j = before.length - 1; j >= 0; --j) {
        if (before[j] == after[i]) {
        table[i][j] = 1 + table[i + 1][j + 1];
      } else {
        table[i][j] = Math.max(table[i][j + 1], table[i + 1][j])
      }
    }
  }
  return table;
}

function findChangeWithTable(table, before, after) {
  const result = [];
  let i = 0, j = 0;
    while(i < after.length && j < before.length) {
      if (after[i] == before[j]) {
        result.push(`${after[i]} is matched`);
        ++i;
        ++j;
      } else if (table[i][j + 1] > table[i + 1][j]) {
        result.push(`${before[j]} is deleted`);
        ++j
      } else {
        result.push(`${after[i]} is added`);
        ++i
      }
  }

  while(i < after.length) {
    result.push(`${after[i++]} is added`);
  }

  while(j < before.length) {
    result.push(`${before[j++]} is deleted`);
  }

  return result;
}


function findChange(before, after) {
  const table = LCATable(before, after);
  return findChangeWithTable(table, before, after);
}
```

Comment: thank you!! I am busy testing it, and it looks correct so far. I really appreciate your help, this is something I have been struggling with. I will do a few more tests, and mark as the answer if they pass.

Comment: I think it is wrong because your algorithm matches elems from after. So it is not symmetrical (however the lcs between two string is)). Consider example 4 in which you pass the test, but the symmetrical "variant": ```findChange( ['B', 'C', 'E', 'A'], ['A', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'B', 'A'])``` does not match three elems

Comment: @grodzi you may be right, added one implementation with LCS , yours seems top down, mine is bottom up, however case 4,5 is still ambiguous .

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the lcs algorithm to find the longest common subsequence.

The recursion is of the form

```
// i the current index in string X
// j the current index in string Y
procedure lcs (i, j) 
  if i == X.length or j == Y.length
    // if we reached the end of string, there is no common subsequence
    // so its size is 0
    return 0
  if X[i] == Y[j] // we can indeed increase our common substring
    return 1 + lcs(i+1, j+1) // continue the recursion by advancing in both string

  // the longest common subsequence is either by advancing one char from X or from Y
  return max(lcs(i+1, j), lcs(i, j+1))
```

Instead of only returning the size, we can keep track of the added index (in say X) when X[i] == Y[j] (see code below)

Note that you will find some dynamic approach on the web, here I just do memoization

In below code, example 5 fails (the number of elem matched is ok) because for some reason you chose to delete elems from array1 before adding elems from array2 (which you do in all other cases)

```js
function diff (X, Y) {
  const cache = new Map()
  const index = (i, j) => [i, j].join('-')
  function lcs (i = 0, j = 0) {
    const idx = index(i, j)
    if (cache.has(idx)) {
      return cache.get(idx)
    }
    if (i === X.length || j === Y.length) {
      const res = { n: 0, v: [] }
      cache.set(idx, res)
      return res
    }
    if (X[i] === Y[j]) {
      const rec = lcs(i + 1, j + 1)
      const res = {
        n: rec.n + 1,
        v: [i].concat(rec.v)
      }
      cache.set(idx, res)
      return res
    }
    const a = lcs(i+1, j)
    const b = lcs(i, j+1)

    const res = a.n > b.n ? a : b
    cache.set(idx, res)
    return res
  }

  function makeDelta (indices, X, Y) {
    let i = 0
    let j = 0
    const delta = []
    indices.forEach(idx => {
      const c = X[idx]
      const j2 = Y.indexOf(c, j)
      for (let y = j; y < j2; ++y) {
        delta.push(Y[y] + ' added')
      }
      j = j2 + 1
      for (let x = i; x < idx; ++x) {
        delta.push(X[x] + ' deleted')
      }
      i = idx + 1
      delta.push(c + ' matched')
    })

    for (let y = j; y < Y.length; ++y) {
      delta.push(Y[y] + ' added')
    }
    for (let x = i; x < X.length; ++x) {
      delta.push(X[x] + ' deleted')
    }
    return delta
  }
  const res = lcs()
  return makeDelta(res.v, X, Y)
}

const examples = [
  [['England', 'Scotland', 'Wales'], ['Scotland', 'Wales'], ['England deleted', 'Scotland matched', 'Wales matched']],
  [['Scotland', 'Wales'], ['England', 'Scotland', 'Wales'], ['England added', 'Scotland matched', 'Wales matched']],
  [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], ['B', 'C', 'E'], ['A deleted', 'B matched', 'C matched', 'D deleted', 'E matched']],
  [['A', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'B', 'A'], ['B', 'C', 'E', 'A'], ['A deleted', 'B matched', 'C added', 'D deleted', 'E matched', 'B deleted', 'A matched']],
  [['B', 'C', 'E', 'A'], ['A', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'B', 'A'], ['A added', 'B matched', 'C deleted', 'D added', 'E matched', 'B added', 'A matched']],
  [['England', 'Scotland', 'Wales'], ['Scotland', 'Wales', 'England'], ['England deleted', 'Scotland matched', 'Wales matched', 'England added']],
  [['A', 'B'], ['C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'], ['C added', 'A matched', 'B matched', 'A added', 'B added']],
  [['A', 'C'], ['C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'], ['C added', 'A matched', 'B added', 'A added', 'B added', 'C deleted']]
];
function toString (arr) {
  return arr.map(x => x.replace(' deleted', '-').replace(' added', '+').replace(' matched','=')).join('')
}
examples.forEach(([array1, array2, expect], i) => {
  console.log('example ', i+1)
  const aDiff = diff(array1, array2)
  let prefix = ''
  if(toString(expect) != toString(aDiff)){
    prefix = '>>>>'
  }
  console.log('exp', prefix, toString(expect))
  console.log('got', prefix, toString(aDiff))
})
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this function using loop.

```
function arraysAreIdentical(arr1, arr2){
    if (arr1.length !== arr2.length) return false;
    for (var i = 0, len = arr1.length; i < len; i++){
        if (arr1[i] == arr2[i]){
            print(arr1[i] + " Matched.");
        }else{
          print(arr1[i] + " Not Matched.");
    }  
    }  
}
```

This is a simple loop which compare each element in both the array and print accordingly. You can check the live [demo here](https://rextester.com/QEZBS48615).

**Edit**

You can get the deleted and matched item in both the array as shown below.
var array1 = ['England', 'Scotland', 'Wales'];
var array2 = ['Scotland', 'Wales'];

```
//To print the deleted itesm.
print("deleted " + array1.filter(x => !~array2.indexOf(x)));

function arraysAreIdentical(arr1, arr2){
    if (arr1.length !== arr2.length) return false;
    for (var i = 0, len = arr1.length; i < len; i++){
        if (arr1[i] == arr2[i]){
            print(arr1[i] + " Matched.");
        }else{
          print(arr1[i] + " Not Matched.");
    }  
    }  
}

//To get the items that exists.
var newArray = array1.filter(x => ~array2.indexOf(x));
arraysAreIdentical(newArray, array2);
```

Here is the [demo given](https://rextester.com/GCRA33988).

Comment: thanks, but this is not correct. The question is not asking to just compare if the two arrays match, it is asking for details on their likeness.

Comment: @Richard Do you want to create another array with output like matched and deleted in case if that one not matched or you are telling something else?

Comment: yes I do want to create an array that hold the statuses. When working out the statuses, it needs to take into account the sequence of entries in array1 and array2, and track what matches/deleted/added from array1 to array2.

Comment: @SurazKumar, I just tested your new answer, and unfortunately it is not correct. It is  not catering for `added` items and also not picking up on a sequence. e.g. `var array1 = ['England', 'Scotland', 'Wales'];
var array2 = ['Scotland', 'Wales', 'England'];` should have two matches, but your solution has no matches.

Comment: @Richard it is giving all three not matched in that case, what is the issue? If you are thinking in array2 you added some new item then you need to take array1 always which has more element.

Comment: @SurazKumar, it needs to return: `'England deleted', 'Scotland matched', 'Wales matched', 'England added'`.